# How to create an executable setup from VC++ and MySQL code?

Tags: c++, mysql, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

I have Visual Studio 2010 and InstallShield Limited Edition Project installed, when I build I get these warnings and an error:

```
ISEXP : warning : -6245: One or more of the project's components contain .NET properties that require the .NET Framework.  It is recommended that the release include the .NET Framework.
Adding merge module 'Visual C++ 10.0 CRT (IA64)' that is a dependency of component 'AK_B_Receipts.exe'
Adding file 'MySql.Data.dll' that is a dependency of component 'AK_B_Receipts.exe'
Merging Visual C++ 10.0 CRT (IA64): C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Merge Modules\Microsoft_VC100_CRT_ia64.msm
ISEXP : error : -6058: Error merging Visual C++ 10.0 CRT (IA64) with module ID C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Merge Modules\Microsoft_VC100_CRT_ia64.msm
ISEXP : warning : -7205: Skipping file F_CENTRAL_msvcr100_i64.5912DA89_A865_3286_983F_6D24CEB5C300 due to unmerged or missing component C_CENTRAL_msvcr100_i64.5912DA89_A865_3286_983F_6D24CEB5C300 in merge module
ISEXP : warning : -7205: Skipping file     F_CENTRAL_msvcp100_i64.5912DA89_A865_3286_983F_6D24CEB5C300 due to unmerged or missing component C_CENTRAL_msvcp100_i64.5912DA89_A865_3286_983F_6D24CEB5C300 in merge module
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: You need to provide more context for your question.

Comment: Are you sure you meant to include the Itanium (IA64) merge module?